# How to prevent duplicate rules being added to the KnowledgeBase

Tags: drools

I have one single knowledge base and there are users who would create rules and submit over a period of time. 
Day 1: 
Rule name : 'Test1'
Rule name : 'Test2'

I have created knowledgePackage and added the package to the konwledgebase.

Now, when the users come on second day and submit another set of rules.
Rule name : 'Test1'
Rule name : 'Test3'

I am creating another knowledgePackage and when adding the package to the same knowledgeBase and it gets added successfully. I am expecting an error to be throuwn that the rule already exists.

How can I find out if the rule already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are others who want to be able to *replace* a rule by defining and adding a different rule with the same name. Ergo, you can't please everybody.

To check, access the KieBase to obtain a list of all rule names:

```
List<String> ruleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
KieBase kBase = ...;
Collection<KiePackage> packages = kBase.getKiePackages();
for( KiePackage kPackage: packages ){
    for( Rule rule: kPackage.getRules() ){
        ruleNames.add( rule.getName() );
    }
}
```